# Using renderText under certain condition Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

i'm newly to the R world and i'm just trying to build a Dashboard on Shiny.
My problem is that i want to display some text only if certain conditions are met in the renderplotly function.

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel("Posti occupati in terapia intensiva"),
sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("region","Scegli regione",unique(as.character(region_dataset$denominazione_regione),)
                    ),
        dateInput("day","Scegli data", min=region_dataset$data[1], max=region_dataset$data[nrow(region_dataset)], format="dd/mm/yyyy",value=region_dataset$data[nrow(region_dataset)]
        ),
    ),
    mainPanel(
        plotlyOutput(outputId = "TI"),
        textOutput(outputId= "text")
    )
),
))
```

This is the ui page and i show you the server

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

   output$TI <- renderPlotly({
       day <- input$day
       region <- input$region
       request <- filter(region_dataset,region_dataset$data==day & region_dataset$denominazione_regione==region)

    plot_ly(as.data.frame(request$terapia_intensiva),
        domain = list(x = c(0, 1), y = c(0, 1)),
        value = request$terapia_intensiva,
        title = list(text = "Posti occupati TI"),
        type = "indicator",
        mode = "gauge+number+delta",
        delta = (reference = as.integer(request$terapia_intensiva[nrow(request$data)-1])),
        gauge = list(
            axis =list(range = list(NULL, request$posti_TI)),
            bar = list(color = "darkmagenta"),
            borderwidth = 3,
            steps = list(
                list(range = c(0, 0.33*request$posti_TI), color = "green"),
                list(range = c(0.33*request$posti_TI, 0.66*request$posti_TI), color = "yellow"),
                list(range = c(0.66*request$posti_TI, request$posti_TI), color = "red")),
            threshold = list(
                line = list(color = "cyan", width = 5),
                thickness = 0.75,
                value = request$posti_TI)))

})
  output$text <- renderText("Numero massimo di posti occupati")
})
```

My problem is that i want to display the text in the panel only if `request$terapia_intensiva>request$posti_TI`
I can't find out a solution to this problem, i've tried using reactive function and conditional panel but with no results. 
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`renderText()` can contain logic, so

```
output$text <- renderText({
  if (request$terapia_intensiva>request$posti_TI) "Numero massimo di posti occupati"
})
```

If the `if()` returns `FALSE`, `renderText` returns `NULL`.  If you want to be explicit, you can always add `else NULL` or `else rturn(NULL)` if you wish.

Comment: Where is `input$type` defined?